# Why can't I vote for my "own" community-wiki answer when "explicit ownership" has been removed?

Tags: support, voting, community-wiki

I made an answer to one of my questions as *community-wiki* because the solution has been provided in a comment and I didn't want to gain any reputation that I didn't deserve.

So I ticked the *community-wiki* checkbox and have been provided with the following warning...

[image]

...where it clearly states that "*doing so will remove explicit ownership* [of the post]".

Therefore, I thought I might be able to up-vote it because "*explicit ownership has been removed*". But when I tried, I have been provided with the usual message saying that I can't vote for my **own** post:

[image]

I understand that I cannot do so when it's not a *community-wiki* answer because I'd be able to gain rep all by myself but it is not the case here.

Why the reason I cannot vote for this post (where "*explicit ownership has been removed*") is because it is my **own** post?

Isn't it a little bit contradictory?

Comment: Probably because removing explicit ownership means implicit ownership is retained. The original revision is still owned by you - it doesn't get relegated to the community user for example.

Comment: It wouldn't gain you reputation points. But an upvote on your own CW answer would still show up in statistics, raise your upvote score for a specific tag, perhaps net you a badge, etc. Also take in mind that the CW flag is in fact reversible, so it would certainly incur a lot of exceptions just to implement that.

Comment: @mario: CW answers don't count into tag scores, but other than that yeah (other badges do count).

Comment: Strange logic.  Any SO user that creates a post that he does *not* think is helpful should not create that post.   So of course he'll vote it helpful, always.  CW was not invented to be some kind of back-door to automatically outscore another post.

Comment: @Hans Passant: That's why reddit starts off every post with an owner upvote (though, strangely as you have said, it can be removed/changed to a downvote if the owner chooses).

Comment: Also, that up votes indicate usefulness of an answer; it is generally not the case that you are in a position to judge that usefulness unless you answered your own question...

Comment: @BenKnoble: He said the answer was given in a comment rather than as an answer, and so he created a CW answer so there'd actually be an answer. Presumably, before doing that, he then tried it, and found out it was useful.

Comment: I understand this particular case @T.J.Crowder but in general (and thus likely the logic behind denying any self up votes) my point still stands

Comment: @BoltClock: I understand that but being told that I cannot upvote the post because it is my *own* post after having removed the explicit *ownership* is still a bit contradictory I think.

Comment: @mario: Then, a "self" up-vote on a CW answer shouldn't raise any statistic but should still be possible IMO.

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR: This question is not about [meta-tag:questions] at all (that tag should *not* be for "asking a question" in general on Meta, which would be utterly useless). It's also not really all that much of a discussion, although that could be argued.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because CW has never had a consistent meaning.

It doesn't ***really*** mean "the community owns it". It seems like it ought to, but I've verified* that the original poster

- still gets badges for it
- still gets notifications for all activity on it
- still gets *bounty rep awarded* if it's an answer
- can still (un)delete it unilaterally
- can't flag anything on it except for mod intervention
- gets *double credit* for every line they contribute to the *CW authorship percentage* displayed
- can vote to close with 250 rep instead of 3k
- [can't change sort order by accepting (if the post was a self-answer)](//data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/371122)
- [still has their revisions and comments highlighted as owner](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272183/there-should-not-be-any-op-highlighting-on-community-wiki-questions)

And if I'm not mistaken** the original owner can also still

- edit the post without review under all circumstances (even if they lose enough rep to drop all the way to 1)
- unilaterally review all suggested edits
- confirm proposed dupes unilaterally
- have votes on the post reversed automatically if detected as part of serial voting patterns against that user

**None** of this is consistent with the idea that it's owned by the community. The community can borrow it when they come over to visit, is all.

CW is a semantic glitch in SO's tidy design, a hack that sort of mostly works, and it's tolerated because it (more or less) fills a real need. But its meaning, in practice, is a jumble of "make it easier for others to mess with, but not *too* easy", "rep-denial!", and "not really a real post" — even after tweaks have been applied and outreach attempted over the years to reduce those negative aspects of its definition.

There are a few feature requests to improve on that (including [one of my own](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181511/promote-the-collaborative-wiki-style-aspect-of-stack-exchange-more/261069#261069)), but I'm not aware of any company plans to improve it in the foreseeable future.

In this particular case, a consistently community-oriented feature probably *would* allow you to upvote, for one main reason: if the community as a whole is maintaining it, your personal approval of it now hinges on how good a job they're doing, since you're not solely responsible for keeping things in line. The fact that this is not permitted is a very good sign that no, the original poster, when push comes to shove, is the one that ultimately should take responsibility for everything there.

<sub>**I've seen these happen, either on my own account or in the wild*</sub>
<sub>***I haven't seen these happen (yet), but know of no reason to suppose they don't*</sub>

Comment: In case anyone's curious, I really don't have a grudge against CW. It's just that as I was working out this answer, I started really realizing just how astonishingly bad a kludge this is and how very far from its notional ideals CW falls.