# Community Wiki questions become abusable instead of immune

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have been following closely on the concept of Community Wiki (CW) answers, and I noticed an interesting effect. Some features of a CW post are:

> - A much lower reputation (**100** instead of **2000**) is needed to freely edit a community wiki post.
> - Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.
>
> Source: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741)

I'm thinking - the main reason for turning content into CW marked is making it common implying that those are questions/answers which are more meaningful to the community, and should be preserved.

So why instead of protecting the content by limiting edits, we encourage more editing by lowering the reputation limit? Or making it easier to downvote by removing the concession of reputation one suffers when downvoting which may affect exposure.

If some content was decided worthy of CW, it's supposed to have value to the community, rather than just the asker, right?

Am I missing something in the essence of CW content?

Comment: How will encouraging more downvotes result in lower quality content?

Comment: @resueman, good point! This was not meant to be just about quality, also exposure.
If some content was decided worthy of CW, it's supposed to have value to the community, rather than just the asker, right?

Comment: @psubsee2003, I understand what you mean, but my point is not about the author or the rep. It's intended at the effect of the different behaviour of CW posts on their content. For instance, I'm worried about taking something that's community-contributed, and has value to several members of the community, and allowing rookies to, probably in some cases, reduce its quality.

Edit: worried might not be the right word. I'm trying to wrap my mind around the thought behind the idea, maybe even in order to better use this tool.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks for letting me know. I've updated it.

Comment: [CW is incoherently designed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306311/4099598), news at eleven. (Allowing lower-rep users to edit is a good idea, but it's not supported by any [mechanism for transferring *responsibility for the content* to the community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261069/274165). [Shameless plugs for my own posts....])

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm thinking - the main reason for turning content into CW marked is making it common implying that those are questions/answers which are more meaningful to the community, and should be preserved.

This is completely false.  Marking a post as CW has nothing to do with the quality, or value, of the content.  It also has nothing to do with preserving the content.

Marking a post as CW is a way of indicating that the post is not owned by the person that is posting it.  It's a way of saying that the content is a collaboration of many different user's contributions, rather than one user's contribution.

Since so many users are contributing to whatever value that post has (high or low) it's not appropriate for only the person who began the post to have their reputation affected by its score.

The reason for the lowered limit on editing is that the whole idea of a CW post is to *encourage other users to collaborate on the content of the post*.  The lowered limit on editing is entirely in line with this goal.  Note that this still counts as activity, so abusive, inappropriate, or simply incorrect edits can still be seen by other users and rolled back if needed.

Comment: I tend to not agree, as the fact something receives positive attention usually indicates it is of value. But it seems like to community agrees. Thanks for the answer!