# Should we add links between equivalent questions in different languages?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, languages, english, cross-posting

On the Russian Stack Overflow site, [there was a proposal to add a feature to Stack Overflow where you could add links to the same content across different languages](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431/176684), similar to the feature on Wikipedia where articles have a list of links to the same article in other languages.

This proposal seemed to be regarded positively by the community, but nothing really happened since it would involve significant effort from the Stack Overflow developers to create.

Instead of waiting for some official feature for linking between the same questions in different languages, we could just edit in these links manually to the foot of questions, similar to how we used to edit in links to duplicates back in the days before they integrated this feature into the close-as-duplicate process.

As they say, it's better to ask for forgiveness than permission, so as an example I added "In other languages" links to the following question in English, Spanish, and Russian:

- [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/546661)
- [¿Qué significa “use strict”?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2184/416)
- [Что значит "use strict"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435546/176684)

There are many similar cross-language equivalent questions. Is it worth linking them together, or does this add too much noise to the questions?

---

In other languages: [Español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/463/416) • [Русский](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2541/176684)

Comment: People here on Meta.SO [seemed to support first-class cross-language links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311564/3614835), so it isn't just your site that is interested.  I'm not sure we should do it manually... but doing so might bump cross-links above the _teams_ and _developer story_ features on the developers' priority list.

Comment: I can understand the use of such links from non-English sites to the English version, but the other way around seems more noisy to me than it is useful. I mean in the English version there is already enough to do with linking duplicates of the same language :)

Comment: @Gumby I don't follow you; they link to same-language duplicates on all the sites. That's not a unique feature of the English Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please leave my questions alone, this is not a good idea to do through manual edits.  Normal questions are not wiki resources, that should be constantly updated with whatever whim resource a particular editor wants.

Comment: @MarkRogers OK, I'll respect your desire to not have your question edited, even though I disagree with the idea that adding links to other languages is whimsical or detrimental. But thanks, this does raise the important practical issue about potential edit wars when users for whatever reason don't want their posts to be edited.

Comment: Automatic translation and a disclaimer for non accurate results like microsoft does would be helpful. Also an option for editing that translation.

Comment: The [same question](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2746/quando-por-que-e-como-utilizar-a-diretiva-use-strict-em-javascript) in PT.SO. Probably there is one in JA.SO and, in the future, the same question will exist in DE.SO, FR.SO, IT.SO, KO.SO, etc. Due to the high amount of edits that it would bring, I disagree with this suggestion. We should wait for a real implementation for this feature.

Comment: I've edited this question to use _equivalent_ instead of _duplicate_ as you don't propose to close any of these questions as duplicates of one another (which wouldn't make much sense).  Some of the answerers seem to have misunderstood.

Comment: @PeterOlson my point is that linking across languages is pretty much a similar feature as linking duplicates. And linking duplicates is already a day job not done by enough people, lets not add more work to the pile that will only get half-done.

Answer (score 2):

No, do not edit the other people's questions with links to similar questions, especially if they are in another language.  The purpose of editing is to make the post better (see [Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and [Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)).  A link to another language would not improve the existing post.

The current convention is to add links to similar questions in the comments.  Be sure that you indicate that the link is for a different language.  Something like *Spanish SO has a similar [question](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).*

That said, I do not think links to other languages will do most SO users any good.  The majority of the answers will already be on SO, so the odds of an SO user speaking enough of the other language to be able to use the answers and there not being an answer on SO with the same content is very low.  In addition, it is not too difficult to search each site you are interested in.  I do not think it is time (yet) for this kind of linking.

For a feature like this to work correctly, it would need to be implemented into the site code so users can opt into the languages they want.

One last though, I usually discourage editors from making changes which would not make it through a review.  We already expect a lot from edit reviewers, asking them to know another language so they can validate a link you added is asking a bit much, especially since this specific type of change is (at best) a questionable improvement.

Answer (score 2):

There is never exactly the same question twice (unless the localized StackOverflows are simply translation services).

It may make sense to link from a localized StackOverflow question to one or more very similar questions from the English StackOverflow but it is much less meaningful to do it the other way around.

The reason is that many more people speak and understand English than is likely for any of the languages of the localized StackOverflows. Very likely the questions here would be cluttered with links to localized StackOverflows whose languages the user doesn't speak. This would not be useful.

Also I guess that almost always a English StackOverflow question is more comprehensive than any other localized StackOverflow version of it. If not, well, very likely I couldn't read it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, we should not support cross-language duplicates.  I believe cross-language duplicates are in the same boat as cross-site duplicates.  As [previous discussion about cross-site duplicates on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates) has pointed out, cross-site duplicates would force two otherwise distinct communities together.  Here are some of the counterarguments:

- Communities expect different knowledge bases from their own users.  Something that is completely obvious and considered "poorly researched" (downvotable) in one community could be obscure in another one.
- You can't expect users to participate in both communities.  While many programmers are multilingual, cross-language duplicates would completely exclude those not proficient in both languages.
- You get different viewpoints and ways of thinking from different communities.  Just as sysadmins think differently from web developers, so too do native English speakers think differently from native Russian speakers.  People asking on SO want an English solution, so Russian duplicates are pretty much irrelevant.  If users want the Russian answer, they would be active in the Russian community.

> Or does this add too much noise to the questions

You should not force cross-language links into your post.  Add the links if they actually improve your post.  And because SO is in English, the cross-language post would have to be amazing to add something of value to the English post.  If you borrow ideas from a RU.SO post (maybe it was asked and answered there first), it's appropriate and mandatory to cite it.  But dropping a shoutout to your buddies in the RU.SO community who just happened to answer the equivalent question is noise.

Comment: "too do native English speakers think differently from native Russian speakers." -- I think that's kind of the point of crosslinking; native Russian speakers who arrive at an English question can now choose to read the Q&A in their native language.  (Note that we are not proposing _closing as duplicate_ here.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I initially overlooked that.  I've edited to clarify your point.

Comment: The question is not about cross-language **duplicates**, and author is not proposing that questions should be closed when they're already answered on another site/language/etc.

Answer (score -1):

The chance of anyone speaking Russian, Japanese, Spanish, or Portuguese and understanding the original English question is actually quite high, but we're overlooking something.

## They want the equivalent question and answer in *their* language.

What's wrong with that?  I don't see any issues with this happening.

The reason is multiple:

- Even if the chances of them understanding English is high as a developer, it's neither a guarantee nor is it indicative of the full understanding that the native translation can provide.
- Programmers that *don't* understand English but can understand Spanish or Russian would be at an acute disadvantage, given the nuance that all natural languages carry.
- Who has the final say?  Is it the English speakers that force this question as the global canonical, or is it the native speakers that accept a foreign-looking question into their community?

With that, I see no reason to go about implementing something like this, or enforcing something like this.  Seems like there are more constructive things to spend one's time on.

Comment: So how about linking from English to other languages, but not the reverse?  (Note that no questions are being _closed_ here, just linked to.)

Comment: `They want to equivalent question and answer in their language` Of course, nobody is contesting that here. What does adding links between identical questions in different languages do to prevent people from seeing questions and answers in their own language? As far as I can see, it only makes *more* people able to find questions and answers in their own language.

Comment: Adding the multiple links I fear would only serve to confuse as opposed to aid.  Chances are, if someone's on the Spanish Stack Exchange, they're there to see questions in Spanish.  Adding links to other languages wouldn't help matters.

Comment: I think that depends on how well Google can send them to the Spanish SO, given that many search terms will be the names of functions, keywords, error messages etc., which are written in English in most programming languages.  I agree Spanish -> Russian probably won't be used much, but English -> * might be more useful.