# Is it allowed to ask identical questions in different languages (not programming languages)?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, languages

Are question duplicates in different languages (localized versions: [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)) allowed?

I have looked through this post: [*Is it OK to translate and repost Stack Overflow questions/answers in different language?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218048/is-it-ok-to-translate-and-repost-stack-overflow-questions-answers-in-different-l)

and this post in Russian: [*translation: Is it allowed to translate questions from Stackoverflow*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/70/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-so)

In first post in **meta.stackexchange** it is recommended NOT to translate questions. In the second post in **meta.ru.stackoverflow** it is stated that translation is OK.

---

My question is not quite about translation questions and answers from different authors, but a bit different matter. Is it allowed to ask identical questions on different StackOverflow sites in different languages? When this happens moderators leave such comment:

> *Cross-posted. Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.*

Obviously, cross-posting is forbidden. But does it apply for questions in different languages?

Is it really like that? If I post same question in different languages does that mean that I waste someone's time? I thought that different language communities considered to be **independent**. Some may search and read the question and answers for it in English while Russians (for example) may do it in their native language (especially those who do not know English).

Comment: It's *still* crossposting, isn't it?

Comment: @Makoto It maybe is cross-posting but how could a non-speaker now that? or understand the information if pointed to it? Surely the idea of having language specific sites is for people that don't English good? Thus directing them to cross-posts in English seems pretty redundant.

Comment: I don't see how directing people comes into the picture. Its crossposting because a singular person posts the same question on multiple sites at the same time. Rather than asking yourself "why not?", really ask yourself where it could turn sour. The first thing that pops into my head is that it is a logistical nightmare. Say that in language A an answer is provided and in language B a completely different answer is provided. What then?

Comment: @Gimby But that's fine, short of having a translator present to copy questions and answers into another language, that is better than the absence of the question on a language specific site. It appears to wrong the asker (who has a smaller pool of answerers available), The smaller language communities that will come second to english every time) , and it's wrong to the community as a whole because if these small language communities are excluded, we lose their creativity in answering.

Comment: I don't have the problem with a main.SO and language.SO having the same question as long as it was done naturally.  Someone on language.SO may never have seen the post on main.SO so, IMHO that is okay.  If you are actively going out though and duplicating content just to have it in multiple languages, then IMHO, you should not be doing that.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [Should we add links between equivalent questions in different languages?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316884/4320665)

Comment: @Gimby *"Say that in language A an answer is provided and in language B a completely different answer is provided."* The exact same thing already happens without cross-posting. It's pretty common for one question to get multiple divergent answers, and it's not a "logistical nightmare."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my view, different language sites are basically separate silos of knowledge. Those sites exist in the first place because many people who do not speak English [very well] have no access to the knowledge "hidden" on the English Stack Overflow. So there exists a site in their native language where they can find and contribute knowledge.

While there are many multi-lingual programmers out there, I would guesstimate that the overlap between different sites is rather small overall. If that wasn't the case and most people could simply access "SO proper," there would be no need to have other versions of it to begin with.

If this hypothesis actually holds true, that means if you post it on SO, mostly only SO visitors will see it. If you post it on ja.SO, mostly only ja.SO visitors will see it. This creates separate silos of knowledge. Which is unfortunate. For that reason I'll go as far as saying that **cross-pollination is important.**

For the most part, cross-posting between different languages should not pose any big issues due to the small overlap. However, practically speaking I'd say that you probably shouldn't spam three or four different Stacks at once just because you happen to speak the languages. I'd recommend posting on your primary site/the site which will most likely attract the best answers first, and cross-posting elsewhere either if you receive no answers or to spread knowledge as a self-answered post.

Comment: The pollination argument only holds if it's a useful question rather than the "please do my homework" or "here's my entire codebase, plz find the bug" that you often see.

Comment: Sure. It goes without saying that *crap* has no place anywhere on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say only do this if taking responsibility for

1. linking the 2+ questions and
2. translating your accepted answer onto the other sites (probably as community wiki).

By the time you have your accepted answer, the others are effectively no longer about ["actual problems that you face"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). So: spam responsibly and clean up after yourself.

---

#2 is also suggested in the [meta.pt.SO post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/737) linked by fedoroqui ("Se você obtém uma resposta melhor em um site, vá colocar essa informação no outro, citando o autor.").

Answer (score -1):

Since this topic is under debate, it would be good to have a network-wide accepted guideline.

For example in Meta Stack Overflow in Portuguese there is a canonical post that says:

> [Onde faço pergunta, SO em Português ou em Inglês?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/737/28073)

That is:

> Where do I ask a question, in SO in Portuguese or in English?

And the accepted answer says:

> Faça em ambos!

That is:

> Do it in both!

The explanation given is that this increases the chances to get an answer.

Comment: By that same reasoning, I've seen people asking the exact same question on 3 or 4 different fora I frequent. And I find it **supremely** annoying. Pardon my Google-translation but I'd rather say "Bem, se ninguém sabe ..." ("Well, if nobody knows..."), coupled with a generous waiting period.

Comment: @RadLexus I agree with you, I am just adding the answer to give an overview on what language-specific sites are dong. I discovered this when I noticed a question was posted both in [pt.so] and in [unix.se]. I flagged and it was declined citing this very post I linked.

Comment: Just for reference: I'm going to leave that downvote. :P (I do understand it's not *your* point, but merely copied from what them Portugeans say.) Related discussion: [Should I encourage people to use the localized versions of SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323148/2564301), which seems to focus on the OP able to understand any answers – i.e., if your english is good enuf to use on Unix&Linux then theres no need for posting on pt.so a swell.

Comment: @RadLexus no problem, it is a meta answer to link to another site's meta debate, so I couldn't expect it to be extremely successful. Note it was not my question what I was talking about, btw. My very point here, and what triggered me to post an answer, is that every site seems to be defining canonical approaches that seem to be in conflict. A general guidance by [se] employees would be good to clarify what is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Oh absolutely. For me, it sounds your flagging was correct and you shouldn't have been flogged in return. It's disconcerting that this issue is viewed differently upon on other language's sites.